# sqflite broke on Android after adding a new table Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I just added a new "Translations" table to the database init and wrote all the crud methods. Commands `db.query` and `db.insert` work just fine, but as tried inside `updateVersion()` either `db.delete` or `db.update` throw the missing plugin error : 
`ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method update on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)`.

After a while I realised that also older two tables are now throwing the same error on delete and update command. Looks like adding a new table broke it all.. I tried flutter clean but nothing changed, so I uninstalled and reinstalled the app, but I still get same errors. I then commented out new table and reinstalled the app but still get the errors..I also tried invalidating the cache a restart but still the same..
On iPhone dough it does not throw any error..

In iOS CoreData kinda behaves the same when you change something.. but with a fresh app install it all resets.. here it seems that the db is still written on disk..
How do I make sure I erased it? I tried `await deleteDatabase(path);`.

Any Idea of what's going on?
As always thank you very much for your time and help.
This is the db:

```
class DBProvider {
  //1.Create a private constructor that can be used only inside the class :
  DBProvider._();
  static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();

  //2.Setup the database
  //Next we will create the database object and provide it with a getter
  //where we will instantiate the database if it’s not (lazy initialization).

  static Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
//    await Sqflite.devSetDebugModeOn(true);
    // if _database is null we instantiate it
    _database = await initDB();
    return _database;
  }
  // If there is no object assigned to the database,
  // we use the initDB function to create the database.
  // In this function, we will get the path for storing the database
  // and create the desired tables:

  initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "Fixit.db");
    //TODO: tried deleting
//    await deleteDatabase(path); // still errors
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE Route("
          "routeId TEXT,"
          "routeName TEXT,"
          "routeDistance TEXT,"
          "routeDuration TEXT,"
          "coordinates TEXT"
          ")");
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE Alarm("
          "alarmId TEXT,"
          "alarmName TEXT,"
          "enabled BOOL,"
          "repeatWeekdays TEXT,"
          "time TEXT,"
          "sound TEXT,"
          "routeName TEXT"
          ")");
//      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE Translations("
//          "version TEXT"
//          ")");
    });
  }

}
```

and these are the CRUD methods:

```
class DefaultsDbRepository {
  var database = DBProvider.db.database;

  Future<int> checkVersion() async {
    final db = await database;
    try {
      var res = await db.query('Translations');
      assert(res != null);
      int version = res != null ? int.parse(res.first['version']) : 0;

      print('checkVersion() db version is: $version');
      return version;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }

  saveVersion({int version}) async {
    print('saveVersion() version to save is : $version');

    assert(version != null);
    final db = await database;
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> map = {'version': version};
      db.insert("Translations", map);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  updateVersion({int newVersion, int oldVersion}) async {
    print('updateVersion() version to save is : $newVersion');
    assert(newVersion != null);

    final db = await database;
    db.delete("Translations");
    try {
//      Map<String, dynamic> map = {'version': newVersion};
//
//      db.insert("Translations", map);
//      db.update("Translations", map); // [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method update on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
//      db.update("Translations", map,
//          where: "version = ?", whereArgs: [oldVersion]);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it work again. After quite a few, uninstall, flutter clean and reinstalls I saw the problem. I was using `'` instead of `"` in my db methods.

So I changed'ed from:

```
saveVersion({int version}) async {
    print('saveVersion() version to save is : $version');

    assert(version != null);
    final db = await database;
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> map = {'version': version};
      db.insert("Translations", map);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

to:

```
saveVersion({int version}) async {
    print('saveVersion() version to save is : $version');

    assert(version != null);
    final db = await database;
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> map = {"version": version};
      db.insert("Translations", map);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

and all commands are working as expected.
Hope this will be of help to others.
Cheers.